# What does it mean "to send something to be + -ed"?

Tags: grammar

i came across this sentnce:

> Either my quarry's inside or this  is where he sends his clothes to be laundered!

I know there is a pattern :

> send something to someone, something, or some place

That is, what is it for ? Why do we need a passive after *send to*?

isn't it right to write like this :

> ... is where he sends his clothes **to the loundry**!

I would be happy to answer, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the pattern you described, *to* indicates the destination (the place where something is being sent). In *this is where he sends his clothes to be laundered*, *to* expresses purpose.

> This is where he sends his clothes (what for?) **to be laundered**.

Compare

> ... the government's decision to send troops **to the region**. (place)

> ... the government's decision to send troops **to resolve the conflict**. (purpose)